# jquery validator method to check if the value matches with the given value and display error

Tags: php, arrays, jquery-validate

I need a basic validation on postcode that is display error if empty and also display error if it matches the given value.

```
var zip_cde = "1234,5095,2356";
postcode: {
       required: true,
       number: true,
       minlength: 4
      },
 <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" placeholder="5095" >
```

i want that if the postcoe matches the **zip_cde**, jquery validator shall display error.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var zip_cde = "1234,5095,2356";
postcode: {
    required: true,
    number: true,
    postalcode: true
    },

jQuery.validator.addMethod("postalcode", function(postalcode, element) {
return this.optional(element) || (postalcode.match(/^([0-9]{4})$/) && $.inArray(postalcode, zip_cde));
}, "Please enter a valid postcode");

 <input type="text" name="postcode" id="postcode" placeholder="5095" >
```